# Django fetch all relations

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I have an app with a similar structure as this snippet

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)

class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

What is the most generic way, that i will be able to use in other apps to fetch all blogs with their category and entries?

I thought about creating a manager for the Blog model, that can fetch all the Categories for that blog, but it's hardcoding the model names

```
 class BlogManager(models.Manager):
     def categories(self):
         return Category.objects.filter(blog=self)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is a [Select Related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related). It returns a QuerySet that will automatically "follow" foreign-key relationships, selecting that additional related-object data when it executes its query. Your query for Blogs would look something like:

```
Blog.objects.select_related().filter( something )
```

or

```
Blog.objects.select_related().get( something )
```

Comment: The problem with this aproach is when i need to access 10 blogs with 20 categories and 40 entries in each category, i will create enourmous amount of db queries, something that i already have.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a standard way?
Filter using Blog's PK with FK relation.

```
Category.objects.filter(blog__pk=self.pk)
```

Comment: Because if i need all entries of all categories of all blogs, i will have to iterate over them twice.