# Django - Is there a way to optimize ORM ManyToOne calls in a loop?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

I see myself having this kind of pattern in my Django views:

```
<ol>
{% for a in ModelA %}
    <li>{{ a.title }}</li>
    <ol>
    {% for b in a.modelb_set.all %}
        <li>{{ b.title }}</li>
        <ul>
            {% for c in b.modelc_set.all %}
                <li>{{ c.text }}</li>
                <ul>
                {% for d in c.modeld_set.all %}
                    <li>{{ d.text }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}
    </ol>
{% endfor %}
</ol>
```

The problem here of course is that this is making n^4 database calls, which is very unscalable. For a single `ModelA` object, I am making about 23 SQL queries, and I assume this number will only go up as the number of `ModelA` queries goes up.

Is there a general way to lower the number of queries that are needed to be made here? Any ideas would be appreciated :)

(If you're curious, the actual code is [here](https://github.com/misingnoglic/polling_app/tree/master/polls) - ModelA is Poll, ModelB is TextChoiceQuestion, ModelC is TextChoice and ModelD is TextChoiceNuance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django fetch all relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909265/django-fetch-all-relations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a model?
If so, I recommend to upload the model code.

I usually code like this.
First, If I use ManyToManyField, use prefetch_related('fields', 'field__subfield', ).

```
Model.objects.prefetch_related('afield', 'afield__bmodel_field', 'afield__bmodel_field__cmodel_field')
```

Seond, you have to use related_name. Regardless ManyToManyField, ForeignKey, you can get a better related name.

```
class CheckList(models.Model):
    """docstring for CheckList"""
    """ 설명 """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.name

class Question(models.Model):
    checklist = models.ForeignKey(CheckList, 
            on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='questions')

# example
check_list = CheckList.objects.prefetch_related('questions').all()
```

Comment: The model code is here: https://github.com/misingnoglic/polling_app/blob/master/polls/models.py

Comment: Good answer, except you absolutely do not need to set a related_name.